# How to tag words in text by hand? (making custom dataset)

Tags: dataset, data-science

I have 500 GB of PDF files that are structured even less constant than web pages. Now I need to make an algorithm to retrieve some points from their heading (author, issuing organization, etc).

I need a tool to label parts of the text and train a model to detect this stuff. Can you propose me a tool to do this? I am definitely not the first one who has this task, so there must be a solution out there.

If you direct me to someone, who asked this previously and got an answer - it will be even better.

FAQ:
RegEx doesn't work.
No, I can not get the list of all organizations for easy matching.
Many names are not European, so it will not work.

Comment: Regarding authors: Data is raw research papers. Without dipping into the project backlog - I need data about issuing organization. Detecting a list of author names is more like a side task that is nice to be completed. If I need to spend the next week labeling data I prefer to solve as many tasks as possible.

I don't process metadata. I have a raw text feed, where this stuff is stored. Example:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07004v3.pdf
So I need a solution to speed up the labeling process.

Comment: I want to beat my head with my keyboard, but it is a laptop... It is too expensive to replace.
I will try this out.